# Get-AzWebAppSlotConfigName for All Configuration Items Not Just Deployment Slot Settings

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am able to retrieve connectionStrings and appSettings that are Deployment Slot settings using Get-AzWebAppSlotConfigName but need to view connectionStrings that are swapped in as part of a Swap Slot so these are not Deployment Slot Settings (ex. I swap in a 2nd Web database and this replaces the current Web database). Here is what I am doing now:

```
$connValues = Get-AzWebAppSlotConfigName -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "mywebapp"
Write-Output = $connValues.ConnectionStringNames
```

Is there another method for obtaining all current Configuration Settings (ex. App Settings and Connection Strings) for a Web App Slot whether they are a Deployment Slot setting or not?

Comment: Are you looking for another method apart from PowerShell command which you are using? @Kode

Comment: Any PowerShell that can get the full list of connectionStrings in a particular slot (whether the connectionStrings are Deployment Slot Settings or not) would be my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the active configuration is within the Site Config if you run a Get-AZWebApp command. This is what allows me to grab the connectionStrings (whether they are Deployment Slot Settings or not):

```
$connValues = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -Name "mywebapp"
Write-Output = $connValues.SiteConfig.ConnectionStrings
```